# New References shown as bold

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, citing

this is my first question here, I am rather a basic user using a comparably complex "thesis" documentclass template, which was probably not the best idea in the first place.

What I do not get why all of newly added references are shown in bold, although they appear in the references.bib file and latex recognizes the source as such:

[image]

The upper reference (Mercer) works, while the Merton reference does not.

[image]. Here is the proof that overleaf actually finds the reference as such.

Here is the yellow message that I get:
[image]

The same issue holds true for about 10-12 other sources that are "read" as sources, but that are not display as such :(

Any help? I Need to submit something by tomorrow evening 8 PM CET, help please!!

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\addbibresource{References10.bib}

\label{Bibliography}
\lhead{\emph{Bibliography}}
\printbibliography
```

\end{document}

This is the code for my references

Comment: Don't post pictures of code, but the code itself instead. Additionally, include all relevant code that allows us to replicate the behaviour. You call your document class a "rather complex 'thesis'" - paste the `\documentclass` here as well, otherwise we might never see exactly what you're seeing/experiencing. Can you do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Do you have any red errors?  Those take precedence, and may cause yellow warnings.  If you could [edit] your post and copy/paste the code instead of posting an image, that would be helpful.  While you're editing, add the [tag:overleaf] tag, since this appears to be Overleaf related.  It would also help to create a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407), although that's more work for something due in a day.

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}; Which codedo mean @Werner? The codes referring to the references?:

Comment: That's some of what Werner meant; they were trying to direct you to a MWEB.  It would really help if you could work your way through that link.  Unfortunately, `Thesis` is not a standard class, so that will make things more difficult.

Comment: It looks like you're not running `biber` between LaTeX runs.

Comment: What would it mean not running biber? how can I then run it?